# Gitlab CI job parallel on different runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to run 2 jobs parallel on a different OS. For this scenario I've to active runners on different servers with the required OS. Each runner has a unique tag, which I use for the jobs. But the jobs are running sequential, not parallel. Is there any keyword which I have to use, to run both jobs parallel?

my gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

rhel8:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $TEST == "rhel8" || $TEST == "all"
  tags:
    - rhel8
  script:
    - echo "Test  RHEL 8"

rhel7:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $TEST == "rhel7" || $TEST == "all"
  tags:
    - rhel7
  script:
    - echo "Test RHEL 7"
```

Comment: As you described your configuration, these jobs _should_ be running concurrently provided that  `TEST == all` and your runners are available. I suspect one of your runners may either not be running or was busy on another job. But the YAML configuration looks fine -- jobs in the same stage are supposed to be able to run together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [parallel](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel) keyword is what you are looking for.  Here is an example of using it to run the same job with different runner tags:

```yaml
stages:
 - test

rhel:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $TEST =~ '/^rhel.*/' || $TEST == "all"
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - TEST: rhel7
      - TEST: rhel8
  tags:
    - $TEST
  script:
    - echo "Test $TEST"
```

Comment: `parallel:matrix` can run on one-dimensional matrix, so `TEST: [rhel7, rhel8]` is work.